# IIS requires certificate to have exportable private key

Tags: ssl, iis

I have a question about an IIS SSL certificate issue that I see repeatedly.
When I import a CA issued SSL certificate into IIS, I have found that it does NOT WORK unless I import it with the private key marked as exportable.
The default certificate import setting for every version of IIS for as long as I can remember is to mark the private-key as NOT exportable.

So if I import the certificate into IIS with private-key not exportable, web browsers like Chrome and Edge will reject it and refuse to load the web page and users get an error message.
(I confirmed the SSL certificate is the problem because the page loads correctly by enabling http/80).
I found that I have to mark the certificate as private key exportable to make it work.

Does anybody else find the same problem ?

Has anyone been able to get IIS to work correctly without the private key marked exportable ?
Why does Microsoft set the default IIS certificate import setting so that by default it DOES NOT WORK?
Does anybody know why IIS requires the private key to be marked exportable when it is installed in order to function properly?

Comment: If Chrome or Edge rejects it, run a report to see what's the problem, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/ssl-diagnostics.html. However, I don't recall IIS requires exportable private key, nor its import wizard sets that.

Comment: Since the client should never have access to the private key, they don't know whether it's exportable or not. Something else is different. Exportable allows you to move your website to a new server without having to get a new SSL cert.

Answer (score 1):

You can install it manualy instead of using IIS Manager.

- Double click the `.pfx` file, that will start the import wizard
- Select "Local Machine" as "Store Location"
- The file path will be right, just continue
- Enter password and do not click "Mark Key as Exportable"
- Place it in Personal store (Web Hosting may also work, had not tested)
- Complete de Wizard

You can also do that using `certlm.msc`.

The certificate will then be available in IIS Manager and will work just fine.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use the certificate by the web server, you must export the private key along with the certificate. Without the private key, data encryption (and therefore secure communications) is not possible.

When exporting the server certificate from the server's personal certificate store, you may not have the option to export the private key. If this is the case, when the certificate was imported, the option to allow the private key to be exported may have been unchecked. This is a security measure to prevent a possible compromise of the server's private key. Since this could be a potential security risk, the option to mark the private key as exportable is not checked by default.

Make sure during the import process that you select the box "mark the private key as exportable."

Every Certificate that you install on the IIS website must have a private key associated with it. Without the private key, the certificate won't work at all - it won't be able to complete the initial SSL handshake.

Comment: The question is not about asking IIS to use a public certificate as server certificate. It is asking why if you import certificate via IIS, you must allow private key to be exportable or the certificate won't work.